# Spring-Boot multi module project load property-file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a Spring-Boot-Application as a multimodule-Project in maven. The structure is as follows:

```
Parent-Project
|--MainApplication
|--Module1
|--ModuleN
```

In the `MainApplication` project there is the `main()` method class annotated with `@SpringBootApplication` and so on. This project has, as always, an application.properties file which is loaded automatically. So I can access the values with the `@Value` annotation

```
@Value("${myapp.api-key}")
private String apiKey;
```

Within my Module1 I want to use a properties file as well (called module1.properties), where the modules configuration is stored. This File will only be accessed and used in the module. But I cannot get it loaded. I tried it with `@Configuration` and `@PropertySource` but no luck.

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:module1.properties")
public class ConfigClass {
```

How can I load a properties file with Spring-Boot and access the values easily? Could not find a valid solution.

**My Configuration**

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:tmdb.properties")
public class TMDbConfig {

    @Value("${moviedb.tmdb.api-key}")
    private String apiKey;

    public String getApiKey() {
        return apiKey;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

**Calling the Config**

```
@Component
public class TMDbWarper {

@Autowired
private TMDbConfig tmdbConfig;

private TmdbApi tmdbApi;

public TMDbWarper(){
    tmdbApi = new TmdbApi(tmdbConfig.getApiKey());
}
```

I'm getting an NullPointerException in the constructor when I autowire the warper.

Comment: can you follow this post? It has code example too. https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2016/11/spring-boot-multi-module-projects-adding-module-specific-property-files.html

Comment: is property file copied to jar ? try to unzip your jar and check if file is there

Comment: Well without more information, it is only a wild guess, as it is stated in the JavaDoc: In order to resolve ${...} placeholders in <bean> definitions or @Value annotations using properties from a PropertySource, one must register a PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.

Comment: I updated my Post. There you can see the configuration and how i try to access the value. I unzipped my war package. Within the war ther is the jar of my module and within the module-jar the is my propertyfile.

Comment: tmdbConfig was not instantiated?

Answer (score 7):

**For field injection:**

Fields are injected right after construction of a bean, before any config methods are invoked. Such a config field does not have to be public. Refer [Autowired annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) for complete usage. Use constructor injection in this case like below:

```
@Component
public class TMDbWarper {

    private TMDbConfig tmdbConfig;

    private TmdbApi tmdbApi;

    @Autowired
    public TMDbWarper(final TMDbConfig tmdbConfig){
            this.tmdbConfig = tmdbConfig;
            tmdbApi = new TmdbApi(tmdbConfig.getApiKey());
    }
```

**(or)**

Use `@PostConstruct` to initialise like below:

```
@Component
public class TMDbWarper {

    @Autowired
    private TMDbConfig tmdbConfig;

    private TmdbApi tmdbApi;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        // any initialisation method
        tmdbConfig.getConfig();
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Autowiring is performed just after the creation of the object(after calling the constructor via reflection). So `NullPointerException` is expected in your constructor as `tmdbConfig` field would be null during invocation of constructor

You may fix this by using the @PostConstruct callback method as shown below:

```
@Component
public class TMDbWarper {

    @Autowired
    private TMDbConfig tmdbConfig;

    private TmdbApi tmdbApi;

    public TMDbWarper() {

    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        tmdbApi = new TmdbApi(tmdbConfig.getApiKey());
    }

    public TmdbApi getTmdbApi() {
        return this.tmdbApi;
    }
}
```

Rest of your configuration seems correct to me.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a Spring Boot multi-module example where you can get properties in different module.
Let's say I have main **application** module, **dataparse-module**, **datasave-module.**

*StartApp.java* in **application** module:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class StartApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SpringApplication.run(StartApp.class, args);
    }
}
```

Configuration in **dataparse-module**. *ParseConfig.java*:

```
@Configuration
public class ParseConfig {
        @Bean
        public XmlParseService xmlParseService() {
            return new XmlParseService();
        }
}
```

*XmlParseService.java:*

```
@Service
public class XmlParseService {...}
```

Configuration in **datasave-module**. *SaveConfig.java:*

```
@Configuration
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ServiceProperties.class)
@Import(ParseConfig.class)//get beans from dataparse-module - in this case XmlParseService
public class SaveConfig {

    @Bean
    public SaveXmlService saveXmlService() {
        return new SaveXmlService();

    }

}
```

*ServiceProperties.java:*

```
@ConfigurationProperties("datasave")
public class ServiceProperties {

    private String message;

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

}
```

*application.properties* in **datasave-module** in *resource/config* folder:

> datasave.message=Multi-module Maven project!
>
> threads.xml.number=5
>
> file.location.on.disk=D:\temp\registry

Then in **datasave-module** you can use all your properties either through @Value.

*SaveXmlService.java:*

```
@Service
public class SaveXmlService {

    @Autowired
    XmlParseService xmlParseService;

    @Value("${file.location.on.disk: none}")
    private String fileLocation;

    @Value("${threads.xml.number: 3}")
    private int numberOfXmlThreads;
    
    ...
}
```

Or through ServiceProperties:

*Service.java:*

```
@Component
public class Service {

    @Autowired
    ServiceProperties serviceProperties;

    public String message() {

        return serviceProperties.getMessage();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had this situation before, I noticed that the properties file was not copied to the jar.

I made the following to get it working:

1. In the resources folder, I have created a unique package, then stored my application.properties file inside it. e.g: com/company/project
2. In the configuration file e.g: TMDBConfig.java I have referenced the full path of my .properties file:

   ```
   @Configuration
   @PropertySource("classpath:/com/company/project/application.properties")
   public class AwsConfig
   ```

Build and run, it will work like magic.

Answer (score 0):

You could autowire and use the [`Enviornment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) bean to read the property

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource(value = "classpath:tmdb.properties")
public class TMDbConfig {

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  public String getApiKey() {
    return env.getRequiredProperty("moviedb.tmdb.api-key");
  }

}
```

This should guarantee that property is read from the context when you invoke the `getApiKey()` method regardless of when the `@Value` expression is resolved by `PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer`.